# Obter IP do computador que está acessando aplicação via node.js

Tags: node.js

Tenho uma aplicação .Net onde para cada acesso é gravado log com IP da maquina de acesso, hora etc.

No .Net eu uso `Request.UserHostAddress` no POST do login para pegar o IP da maquina que está acessando a aplicação(a mesma roda em rede local então isso é o suficiente).

Agora estou migrando a aplicação para node e surgiu a dúvida, existe um equivalente  ao `Request.UserHostAddress` em node (processe no backend as informações da máquina que está acessando a aplicação) ou será necessário fazer a obtenção da informação pelo frontend?

Comment: Você tá utilizando alguma biblioteca, como Express? Ou somente Node.js?

Comment: @LuizFelipe estou usando a express nesse momento.

Comment: Já tentou `req.ip()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve considerar alguns cenários para recuperar o IP:

```
var remoteIp = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',').pop() || // Recupera o IP de origem, caso a fonte esteja utilizando proxy
                 req.connection.remoteAddress || // Recupera o endereço remoto da chamada
                 req.socket.remoteAddress || // Recupera o endereço através do socket TCP
                 req.connection.socket.remoteAddress // Recupera o endereço através do socket da conexão
```

Com isso você garante recuperar um endereço remoto, esteja ele utilizando proxy ou não.